# Tomcat shutdown doesn't kill the process associated with DB connection whereas Http & AJP process are killed with shutdown.sh

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat shutdown.sh kills the process associated with Http & AJP port, whereas database process are not killed. 
I am not sure why the database process doesn't terminates.

Database connection

```
<Resource 
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" 
auth="Container" 
maxIdle="233"
maxTotal="377" 
maxWaitMillis="10000" 
removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
testOnBorrow="true" 
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
password="****" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@****:**:**" 
username="******"/>
```

**before ./shutdown.sh**

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8012       :::*     LISTEN      12984/java
tcp        0      0 :::8114                     :::*     LISTEN      12984/java
tcp        0      0 :::8117                     :::*     LISTEN      12984/java
tcp        0      0 :::9017                     :::*    LISTEN      12984/java
tcp        0      0 *******:58142          *******      ESTABLISHED 12984/java    --> DB connection
unix  2         [ ]          STREAM     CONNECTED   23538964        12984/java
```

**after ./shutdown.sh**

```
tcp        0      0 *******:58214          *******       ESTABLISHED 12984/java     --> DB connection
unix  2             [ ]      STREAM      CONNECTED     23538964     12984/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
maxTotal="377" 
maxWaitMillis="10000"
```

IMHO you should switch them back to `maxActive` and `maxWait` respectively. 
Please see: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Database_Connecion_Pooling

> Note that the above changes are not needed if you are using Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool (or any 3-rd party database connection pool implementation).